# Mistaken use trim() function in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, trim

SQL command gave not expected result.

```
UPDATE table SET DATE_COL=trim(DATE_COL).
```

No error message was generated.

I mistakenly used TRIM() to remove space on a column of date type in an Oracle table. The result was this: if the date was between (30.12.1899-31.12.1949) then 100 years are added to the result. If the range was (1.1.1950...31.12.2049) then 100 years are subtracted. If the range is 1.1.1950-31.12.2049, the result will not change. Of course, it shouldn't be used at all for a date type.

Warn about using trim() on the wrong object

Comment: What is your question? Yes, you shouldn't use trim on something other than text. You've got the wrong century because of implicit conversion  - effectively `to_date(trim(to_char(date_col)))` - using your NLS settings, which presumably have `DD-MON-RR`, so the result is expected. (If you had non-midnight times you've lost those too... but maybe you meant to use `trunc()` so that's OK?)

Comment: Why do you store dates in a character type column?

Comment: @jarlh - it says it's "a column of date type", as it should be; trim is just implicitly converting it to a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET DATE_COL=trim(DATE_COL)
```

Then you are effectively doing:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET DATE_COL = TO_DATE(TRIM(TO_CHAR(DATE_COL)))
```

Which is the same as:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET DATE_COL = TO_DATE(
                 trim(
                   TO_CHAR(
                     DATE_COL,
                     ( SELECT value
                       FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
                       WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
                   )
                 ),
                 ( SELECT value
                   FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
                   WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
               );
```

If your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` then nothing will happen to your dates.

But if you `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD-MON-RR` then the date `1920-01-01T12:34:56` would be converted to `01-JAN-20` and then converted back to the date `2020-01-01T00:00:00` which would change the century (since the `RR` format model would interpret `20` as being the current century `2020`) and truncate the time components to midnight.

The simplest solution is to use `ROLLBACK` to restore the database to the most recent commit. If you have already committed then you will need to restore the table from a recent backup.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour might not be what you wanted or expected, but it's what the documentation says will happen. [The trim function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRIM.html) says:

> Both trim_character and trim_source can be VARCHAR2 or any data type that can be implicitly converted to VARCHAR2.

and dates can be [implicitly converted](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-98BE3A78-6E33-4181-B5CB-D96FD9DC1694) to strings, and vice versa.

When you do `trim(DATE_COL)` the date value is implicitly converted to a string, as if you'd done `trim(to_char(DATE_COL))`, and that will use your NLS settings, specifically NLS_DATE_FORMAT. From what you're seeing you appear to have that set to 'DD-MON-RR'. So for example 1899-12-31 is formatted as the string '31-DEC-99'. That string value is then trimmed, which has no effect. Note that if the original date had a non-midnight time, that has also now been lost.

Then when you assign that value back to the date column with `DATE_COL=trim(DATE_COL)` it is implicitly converted back, effectively doing `DATE_COL=to_date(trim(to_char(DATE_COL)))`. The `to_date()` again uses your NLS settings, so for that example date you're now doing `DATE_COL=to_date('31-DEC-99')`. As that also uses NLS_DATE_FORMAT, it's really `to_date('31-DEC-99', 'DD-MON-RR')`, and the [RR format element](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-6C75461E-2E18-4C35-9EB4-038A7E1C9C1F) behaviour says that will be interpreted as 1999.

You can see what happens to a range of dates [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LtIPZEW3), with the intermediate string value and how it's converted back to a date.

| OLD_FULL_DATE | OLD_STR | NEW_DATE | NEW_FULL_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1849-12-31 23:59:59 | 31-DEC-49 | 31-DEC-49 | 2049-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 1850-01-01 00:00:00 | 01-JAN-50 | 01-JAN-50 | 1950-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1899-12-31 00:00:00 | 31-DEC-99 | 31-DEC-99 | 1999-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 1900-01-01 00:00:00 | 01-JAN-00 | 01-JAN-00 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1949-12-31 00:00:00 | 31-DEC-49 | 31-DEC-49 | 2049-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 1950-01-01 00:00:00 | 01-JAN-50 | 01-JAN-50 | 1950-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1999-12-31 00:00:00 | 31-DEC-99 | 31-DEC-99 | 1999-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | 01-JAN-00 | 01-JAN-00 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2049-12-31 00:00:00 | 31-DEC-49 | 31-DEC-49 | 2049-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 2050-01-01 00:00:00 | 01-JAN-50 | 01-JAN-50 | 1950-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2099-12-31 00:00:00 | 31-DEC-99 | 31-DEC-99 | 1999-12-31 00:00:00 |

That fiddle also shows you would have kept the century (but still truncated the time) if you'd had a 4-digit year in your NLS_DATE_FORMAT. Not that you should rely on implicit conversion or NLS settings anyway, it's just demonstrating the effect.

So it's doing what you told it to, unfortunately.

No error message was generated because that's what's supposed to happen. The database can't guess what you are trying to do - it only knows what you *told* it to do - or when you do and don't intend to rely on implicit conversion. The onus is on the coder to use the appropriate functions for whatever they are trying to achieve.